# SQL Select rows on different tables that have the same FK values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, foreign-keys

I need to create a query that list every people able to speak in a country with all the required  languages. I have 3 tables ( country / Language / People) The problem is that I don't have a link between the table Country and People but each table have a foreign key "Language_Id". My goal is to list every people that have as much language as the Country .
Here is an example :

Table People :

```
     ID   Name    Language_ID  
1.   1    Paul    1
2.   2    Paul    2
3.   3    Max     1
4.   4    Ben     2
5.   5    Paul    3
6.   6    Ben     3
```

Table Language :

```
     ID   Name
1.   1    English
2.   2    Dutch
3.   3    French
```

Table Country :

```
     ID   Name         Language_ID
1.   1    France       3
2.   2    Netherlands  1
3.   3    Netherlands  2
4.   4    Belgium      2
5.   5    Belgium      3
```

Result table :

```
       Name    Country_Name
1.     Paul    France
2.     Paul    Netherlands
3.     Paul    Belgium
4.     Ben     Belgium
5.     Ben     France
```

So , Max is excluded from the results because he doesn't have all the required languages.

I am running SQL Server 2016 Std edition.

Could you help me to find a solution ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why is Ben only shown with Belgium and not also France, he has all the required langauges for France?

Comment: My bad... you got it , I just edit the post . Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Can you tag the particular  SQL flavor you're using?

Comment: I am working on a 2016 SQL server Std edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join` and aggregation.  The one tricky part is counting the number of languages within a country to be sure that a person speaks all of them:

```
select p.name, c.name, c.num_languages
from people p join
     (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by name) as num_languages
      from country c
     ) c
     on p.language_id = c.language_id
group by p.name, c.name, c.num_languages
having count(*) = c.num_languages;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way can use a CTE to count the languages per country and then spoken by each person and to filter where the languages spoken per person is at least that required for each country:

```
with c as (
    select name Country_Name, language_id, 
      Count(*) over(partition by name) LanguageCount
    from country
), p as (
    select p.name, c.Country_Name, c.LanguageCount,
      Count(*) over(partition by p.name, c.Country_Name)Languages
    from c join people p on p.Language_ID=c.language_id
)
select distinct p.name, p.Country_Name 
from p
where Languages>=LanguageCount;
```

See [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=44c594f4d15cba401b2c34c2f22eea79)

Answer (score 0):

If you build every combination of languages spoken by each person and match it to the requirements of each country you can get what you're looking for.

```
With build as (
    Select Name, cast(language_id as varchar) as languages, language_id as last_lang
    From People
Union All
    Select a.Name, a.languages + ';' + cast(language_id as varchar) as languages
          , b.language_id as last_lang
    From build a Inner Join People b On a.Name=b.Name
    Where a.last_lang<b.language_id
)
Select P.Name, C.Name
From (
    Select Name,
          String_Agg(cast(language_id as varchar), ';') Within Group (Order By language_id) as Language_Reqs
    From Country
    Group By Name
) C Inner Join build P on P.Languages=C.Language_Reqs
```

This technique can also be modified to identify where individuals might be lacking in requirements.